# add new object in IOC container without having to specify every consturctor param

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, ioc-container, service-provider

I'm trying to add a class to my scoped service in .net core 2.1, I don't want a provider to get all the services needed to satisfy the params of the constructor. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
services.AddScoped<BarcodePage>((provider) =>
    new BarcodePage(provider.GetService<IObservationRepository>(),
        provider.GetService<IPageFactory>(),
        provider.GetService<IMediator>(),
        provider.GetService<IUserRepository>()));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just register it as

```
services.AddScoped<BarcodePage>();
```

The container will resolve the BarcodePage class dependencies for you.